# Python - asynchronous IPC

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, ipc, python-multiprocessing

In the main process, I consume a queue, and execute a callback on dequeue. That callback makes an HTTP request to another process in the same host, which spawns multiple worker processes p1, ..., pN. All this happens asynchronously, and I can attach callbacks that execute when p1, ..., pN finish executing.

The callbacks attached to the `p`'s need to write data (relatively small `dict` instances) back to the main process, to be enqueued into a response queue.

What's the best way to do this? I'm thinking of using `multiprocessing.connection.Listener` and having the `p`'s write to a temporary file, but I'd like this to happen asynchronously, and without having to poll the file for changes.

Comment: Why are you using an HTTP request between your first two processes if the server's worker processes need to talk to the client directly? Why not have the client kick off the workers itself?

Comment: Good question. It's because the server is 3rd party software that I'm using. It does have an API that clients can use to kick off the workers themselves, but I'd be losing some of the [benefits](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) of going through the server.

Comment: Ironically, that benefit is process management.